# Get attribute value within after tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to get hold of the link using Scrapy but unable to do so. Any help would be appreciated and I just started with web scraping.

[image: Snippet of the HTML code]

As you can see there's an attribute `src` in the class `.P2llUzsDMi`. I am trying to scrape the link using `response.css`

`response.css(".P2llUzsDMi ::attr(src)").extract()`

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to (you need to mention the image tag as well)

```
response.css('.P2llUzsDMi img::attr(src)').extract() # use extract_first() to get only one
```

Comment: I tried your code but it returned 'None', even the class I input ```response.css('.P2llUzsDMi')``` also return None, however other random class return some value. Perhaps the website block the spider from crawling for the links?

Comment: are you in the correct div tag, plz show the code for debugging

Comment: tell the website name

Comment: The website I am trying to scrape is ```carousell.sg```. ```https://imgur.com/nRe2yHK``` Here a snippet of my output and codes. Please have a look and tell me where did I do it wrongly. Thank you :)